# How to write query to fetch data from table with sub query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Case is I have one visit table and one lab_order table and lab_order table is used to store the orders with visit_id, test_id, lab_analyte_id where test and lab_analyte is diff tables.

Now I have to find out which Lab_Analyte is not ordered for visit. And to find out I have lab_analyte id so with that I need to check lab_order table with lab_analyte_id is record exists or not and in return I want visit.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Why do you want a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

**Google it. You will get many tutorial sites, Refer any !!**

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm
>
> https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery

Answer (score 0):

1) Your join is not correct, if you are using a left join, you need to specify an on condition, the current join is not a left join but just a cross join.

```
select * from A a 
left join B b
on a.Id=b.Id
where a.Id=1 
and b.Id <> 5
```

Also the group by will fail if there is no aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LAB_ANALYTE_ID  FROM LAB_ANALYTE WHERE LAB_ANALYTE_ID NOT IN (SELECT 
LAB_ANALYTE_ID FROM LAB_ORDER)
```

Every time a record is inserted onto the `LAB_ORDER` table, an `non-null LAB_ANALYTE_ID` will be generated for that record.  We can exclude those `LAB_ANALYTE_IDs` from the result by using the `NOT IN` clause.